# Views header language in url

Tags: views, 8

I am trying to add a link in views header. I enabled multilingual module. Added a Global Textarea in the header. Then added

```
<a href="/my-tickets">Click</a>
```

I want to set the url as

```
<a href="SELECTED_LANGUAGE_CODE/my-tickets">Click</a>
```

So the link may be

```
<a href="en/my-tickets">Click</a>
```

or

```
<a href="fr/my-tickets">Click</a>
```

SELECTED_LANGUAGE_CODE is the language selected in the url.

English version of my site is http://example.com/en
French version http://example.com/en

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the token [site:url] which includes the languages prefix:

```
<a href="[site:url]/my-tickets">Click</a>
```

Comment: this creates a problem when the url is multiple locations. if they're on a default version of the site, the result would be https://website.com//my-tickets - the double hashmarks creating a broken link